# dateTime changes from POSIXct to factor when averaging - R

Tags: r, posixct

I have the following example:

```
begin_date = as.POSIXlt("1990-01-01", tz = "GMT")
# 30 year dataset
dat = data.frame(dateTime = begin_date + (0:(24*30*20)) * (1800))
dat = within(dat,{speed = runif(length(dateTime), 1, 10)
})
```

I wish to calculate the hourly averages, so I use:

```
data <- aggregate(dat[colnames(dat)[2:length(colnames(dat))]],
                  list(dateTime = cut(dat$dateTime,breaks = "hour")),
                  mean,
                  na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, the class of the dateTime column has changed from POSIXct to factor:

```
> class(dat$dateTime)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> class(data$dateTime)
[1] "factor"
```

Why is this the case, and how can I change it back to be POSIXct?

Comment: `?cut` says the return value is a factor...

Comment: How would I return it to POSIXct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 data$dateTime <- as.POSIXct(as.character( data$dateTime))
```

Comment: If I include this in a function, it changes the entire data frame to POSIXct not just the dateTime column

Comment: you might want to double check this one--worked fine for me. But time zone also needs to be specified to be consistent with data in the original question

Answer (score 1):

You can make the hourly bins using `seq` and `findInterval`

```
rng <- range(dat$dateTime)
rng[1] <- rng[1] - (as.numeric(rng[1]) %% 3600) #subtract remainder after div by 3600    secs
hrs <- seq(rng[1],rng[2],by="hour") #sequence by hour
bins <- hrs[findInterval(dat$dateTime, hrs)] #identify the start of hourly interval for each row in dat
```

then use `bins` instead of `cut`

```
data <- aggregate(dat[colnames(dat)[2:length(colnames(dat))]],
                  list(dateTime = bins),
                  mean,
                  na.rm = TRUE)

> class(dat$dateTime)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

> class(data$dateTime)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: slight problem with this is that it doesnt not return the data to the closest hour. For example, say if you had dateTime at 30 min interval, it is not guaranteed hat the return output will be as one point on each hour, rather than 10:30 11:30 etc